# How to join the tables in mysql to get wall messages and comments with name of person ? Only user and his friends messages

Tags: mysql, database-design, select, relational-theory

I have four tables in my mysql database as shown in the image url provided. I want to select data from the tables without duplication. I want to show messages and comments on wall according to the session on username (messages and comments of friends and user itself on user wall). Please help me out.[image]